# Space between ticks [axis]

Tags: pgfplots, axis

I am using the pgfplots package. My objective is to have the x axis with ticks between 10 and 100 (10,20,30,...,100) but the space between them must be reduced by half after each tick. If the space between 10 and 20 is x, then the space between 20 and 30 should be x/2, the space between 30 and 40 x/4 and so on. Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've tried so far.

Comment: Look up semilogxaxis.

Comment: Any success with the suggestions given?